# What tier types do I need for webapps/functions to access a KeyVault locked from public networks?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to close down a KV from public networks. I tried just filtering IPs but I have a functionapp using Premium, so the IPs can change. So what I'm wondering is: ​what is the cheapest way to lock down a KV? Can I setup a VNET to be used only to connect to KV, leaving function app/web app open? I only want to restrict access to the KV, not the function apps and web apps, they can stay open. Any ideas on how to implement this? All the tutorials I have seen close down the functions/web apps as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a private endpoint on the Vnet. It enables you to connect to your Keyvault from the private network without being exposed to internet.

On the other hand, your web app should have access to that Vnet in order to access to Keyvault. You make [a Vnet integration for that purpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-vnet-integration-enable)

**The VNet integration feature:**

- Requires a Standard, Premium, Premium v2, Premium v3, or Elastic Premium App Service pricing tier.
- Supports TCP and UDP.
- Works with App Service apps and function apps.

Comment: But how do I give web apps access to the VNET without closing the web apps as well? Is this even possible?

Comment: Updated the answer. No, you are not obliged to close public access

Comment: I'll try that out, thanks!

Comment: @ryansan,  have you tried it? please accept the answer if this solution worked out for you.